# Fisher-Yates shuffle in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, shuffle

This is my first time making a function just from reading about it on Wikipedia, so I'm sure there's room for a lot of improvement.

```
function fisherYates(str) {
  let result = '';
  for (let i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
    let rand = (Math.random()*str.length)|0;
    result += str[rand];
    str = str.slice(0, rand) + str.slice(rand+1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I know it is 10 years old and pertains to arrays instead of strings, but you mind find [this post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/shuffling/?r=31644) interesting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Mostly just style

Why add the variable `len` inside the for loop. It is a constant so put it outside the loop as one.

The variable `result` is in function scope. Use `var` rather than `let`.

The variable `rand` does not change inside the loop so it should be a `const`.

The expression to get the random number does not need the (...) as operator precedence ensures that the `|` is applied correctly.

Add some spaces between operators for readability. eg `(Math.random()*str.length)|0;` is better as `(Math.random() * str.length) | 0`

#### One issue

The only problem is that you have one to many iterations. The last random value will always be to select from a 1 character string, so it is not needed. You need only iterate the string length minus one.

#### The rewrite

How I would rewrite your code. I personally don't like putting the `let` inside the for loop, so I put the declaration in the scope above. This is because for loops can have a lot of noise (clutter) and that reduces it a bit. Also the function is so short and simple variable names can be shortened without problem, I would make `rand` just the `r`.

```
function fisherYates(str) {
  var i, result = '';
  const len = str.length - 1;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i ++) {
    const r = Math.random() * str.length | 0;
    result += str[r];
    str = str.slice(0, r) + str.slice(r + 1);
  }  
  return result + str;
}
```

Comment: I'd go the other way and change `rand` to `randomIndex`, but each to his own, I guess.

Comment: I'd also declare each variable in the smallest lexical scope, using `let`.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury Block scope has its place but without a clear need its should not be used. You use scope to protect a variable's name, but good function design (no rambling 100+ line functions) eliminates that as an issue (no risk in a 8 line function of using the same variable name by mistake). So i go on the side of efficiency, each scope declaration requires a heap assignment and additional context stack work. In nested loops this can contribute considerable overhead for no good reason but that of "protecting against  incompetent programmers"

Comment: I didn't know that `let` was that inefficient in JavaScript... Anyway, your comment should IMO be a part of your answer. Especially given that almost every article about ES6+ online is preaching about how `var` is outdated and `let` should be used everywhere.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury `var` is part of the language, and very good code was written before the introduction of `let`. `Let` can be dangerous. eg `for(let i = 0; i < 100; i ++){ let a=[...largeArr]; setTimeout(()=>console.log(i),1) }` The callback closes over 100 `i`s  and 100 copies of `arr` but replace `let` with `var` and memory consumption is reduced by 100 (Imagine 100,000+ iterations), but this is not immediately evident, and preaching of let's virtues, alongside of anon function expressions, is resulting in some very bad code. If I speak up in Answers I get downvoted, so I keep it low key.

Comment: Wow! JavaScript implements lexical scoping with closures? That's... of which implementations do you know for it to be true? Is it true for V8? I'd think that they'd associate a (mutable) scope-bindings object to each lexical block - like in Python.

Comment: Also, have a +1!

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury That is standard in the language since day one (1995). Implementation method is not part of the language spec, V8 uses a "context" object which carries the scope chain. The scope is mutable so I guess it is similar to Python (though I am not familiar with python's inner workings)